# How to instantiate an extended class with a different base implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection

I'm working with a binary that contains an object and the base class it extends. I want to instantiate the object, but for it to use my own implementation of the base class. I can see in the base class to know what methods I need t extend.

The problem is that the base class implements a method called "WriteFeed" that expects network connections and writes data out to a network stream. I would like it to use my implementation so WriteFeed can instead dump data to console.

I cannot change the existing binaries, only the way I consume and instantiate it.

Comment: I can't imagine there's any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is to use a composite approach. I'm not sure if this will meet your need or you have visibility access, but it may work.

```
public class SomeBaseClassInSomeBinary
{
   protected virtual void Method1(...) {}
   protected virtual void WriteFeed (...) {}
} 

public class SomeClassInSomeBinary: SomeBaseClassInSomeBinary
{
   protected override void Method1(...) { base.Method1(...); }
   protected override void WriteFeed (...) { base.WriteFeed (...); }
} 

// **** your code
public class MyCode: SomeBaseClassInSomeBinary
{
     private SomeClassInSomeBinary Composite = new SomeClassInSomeBinary();

     protected override void Method1(...) { Composite.Method1(...); }
     protected override void WriteFeed (...) { your implementation }
}
```

}

All you need to do is now use your object instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the idea but I don't think that will work. The problem is that the instantiated class calls its own base.WriteFeed() which is why I need to swap out the implementation of the base class.

Comment: Not problem. It's really hard to see exactly your issue/concern. I'm always here to help.

Comment: What I'm actually doing is just changing the base class to not have any specialized 'write' methods, but rather passing in a write-adapter (or handler if you prefer that terminology). This means when I test it locally I'll pass in a test-adapter, and in production I will pass in the production adapter code.